# Sharepoint Library: Column Limit

Tags: column, library, onedrive-for-business, synchronisation, limitations

[image]

I am syncing a folder of files between OneDrive Business and a Sharepoint Library with CloudHQ. The sync works fine, however, when I try to modify the columns by adding a column from an existing columns on the site, I received the message: "The column cannot be added because the total size of the columns in this list exceeds the limit. Please delete some other columns first."

When I check the columns in the list settings, I see I have over 200 of single line text columns that I believe is a result of the sync. How can I over come this? It seems tedious to go column by column deleting each column. Does anyone have helpful advice?

Comment: Do these columns contain the same part in their names?
If so the powershell script would be best.

Answer (score 1):

SharePoint has 255 text column limit.  You can check [this link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/install/software-boundaries-and-limits) for more info.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I verified syncing with CloudHq (OneDrive to SharePoint site), and it does not seem to create a new column. You may want to verify what is wrong with the source or the sync settings.

You may use PnP powershell, to delete the columns.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/remove-pnpfield?view=sharepoint-ps

Here is a sample:

Install-Module SharePointPnPPowerShellOnline

$username = "user@tenant-xyz.onmicrosoft.com"

$password = ConvertTo-SecureString "password-xyz" –asplaintext –force

$WebURL = "https://tenant-xyz.sharepoint.com/sites/CloudHq"

$credentials = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($username, $password)

Connect-PnPOnline -Credentials $credentials -Url $WebURL

Remove-PnPField -List "Shared Documents" -Identity "SingleLine"